# Android ndk-gdb debugging into distributed .so

Tags: android, android-ndk, gdb, gdbserver

We have a "core" set of native code that will be distributed to Android developers, from it they can link it to their own native code. So there is two .so in the Android .apk. To aid in debugging we'd like to be able to debug into our "core" .so when it wasn't explicitly compiled in the same project.

To clarify.

1) ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1 is run in the distributable.

2) The resulting "core" .so is included in our Android.mk file for the dependent project (a test app in this case)

3) We run the ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1 on the test app.

Everything will compile and run as required, but we can only debug into the "test" .so. I have a high level understanding on how ndk-gdb links in using the gdb.setup file (created via enabling NDK_DEBUG) under the libs folder. I'm currently trying to hack together some way of including both.

Has anyone done something similar? I've searched around pretty heavily and found no results. We can compile the "test" project and the "core" project native aspects into a single .so and debug into any of the native source code (core or test), unfortunately this isn't a good test of our intended result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing, are you loading the library in your first activity? otherwise gdb will not load it. check this question: [Android GDB is not loading c++ shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532229/android-gdb-is-not-loading-c-shared-library/21533990#21533990)